# Impossible to unjoin a machine from AD : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to unjoin a machine from the AD with this command:

```
Remove-Computer -computername $ComputerName  -UnjoinDomainCredential $credential -Restart -Force -PassThru -Verbose
```

but I get this error:

> Remove-Computer : Failed to unjoin computer 'xxx-xx-xxxxx' from domain
> 'xx.corp.xxxxxx.com' with the following
>
> error message: No mapping between account names and security IDs was
> done

I can't login to the machine. I get the error

> The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain
> failed

Any insight?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the full command you're using. I believe you need to specify the `-UnjoinDomainCredential` and possibly also the `-LocalCredential` parameter(s) to do so. After unjoining, you need to restart the machine and logon to the workstation with a LOCAL account

Answer (score 2):

I've executing this commands :

```
$computername = 'XXXXX'

$instance = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $computername -ClassName 'Win32_ComputerSystem'

$invCimParams = @{
    MethodName = 'UnjoinDomainOrWorkGroup'
    Arguments = @{ FUnjoinOptions=0;Username="Administrator";Password="mypassword" }
}
$instance | Invoke-CimMethod @invCimParams
```

I found the solution here:

[CIM METHOD](https://adamtheautomator.com/trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-the-primary-domain-failed/#Fixing_the_Problem_Rejoining_the_Domain)

Comment: Worked for me when I had the same error as OP using `Remove-Computer` - thanks!